# Smooth compactly supported function with good scaling with respect to the fractional Laplacian

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Is there a smooth cut off function with compact support such that $\phi: \Omega \subset \mathbb R^N \to \mathbb R$, $\mathrm{supp} \phi \subset B_R(0) \subset \Omega$ and $$(-\Delta)^s \phi \le C R^{-2s} \text{ and } D^k(-\Delta)^s \phi \le C R^{-2s - k}?$$

Here (-\Delta)^s denotes the spectral fractional Laplacian

Comment: Yes, any function $\phi_R(x) = \phi(x/R)$ will do the job. This is because if $0 \in \Omega$, then the kernel of the "spectral" fractional Laplacian $(-\Delta_\Omega)^s$ is locally very similar to that of $(-\Delta)^s$.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki If the center of the ball is not $0$ and $0\notin \Omega$,is this true anyway?